# Two ways of defining image in an abelian category

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}} $
$\newcommand{\coim}{\operatorname{coim}} $
$\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}$
$\newcommand{\coker}{\operatorname{coker}}$
$\newcommand{\coeq}{\operatorname{coeq}}$

Let's say we are working in an abelian category $\mathcal A$ and take a morphism $f\colon X\to Y$. The image and coimage as usual are defined by $\im(f)=\ker(\coker(f))$ and $\coim(f)=\coker(\ker(f))$. Inspired by the image in the category $\mathbf{Set}$, we can define alternatively
$$\Im(f):=\coeq(X\times_YX\rightrightarrows X).$$
My question is

> Are these two definitions equivalent? I.e. does $\im(f)\cong\Im(f)$ hold?

For this, I intend to use their respective universal properties to obtain unique morphisms $\coim(f)\to\Im(f)$ and $\Im(f)\to\coim(f)$, so that again by their respective universal properties we get $\coim(f)\cong\Im(f)$, while in an abelian category $\im(f)\cong\coim(f)$ and we're done. To get the unique $\Im(f)\to\coim(f)$, we can consider the commutative diagram
[image]

from which we see that $\coim(f)$ coequalizes $X\times_YX\rightrightarrows X$. I'm stuck at getting the inverse direction $\coim(f)\to\Im(f)$, for which I want to show the composite $\ker(f)\to X\to\Im(f)$ being $0$. By far the best I've got is

[image]

where $p_1,p_2\colon X\times_YX\to X$ are the canonical projections. From the universal property of coequalizers we get a unique $\Im(f)\to Y$, and the composite $\ker(f)\to X\to \Im(f)\to Y$ is $0$. But I cannot see whether $\Im(f)\to Y$ is a monomorphism.

Any idea/hint is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes. What you've defined is called the regular coimage; it generalizes the coimage and has the same universal property as it. Similarly the equalizer of the cokernel pair $Y \rightrightarrows Y \sqcup_X Y$ is the regular image, generalizes the image, and has the same universal property as it. See: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coimage

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks a ton for this!!